# Understanding how reader monad simulates global variables

Tags: haskell, monads

From what I understand now the WAY that a monad tries to simulate a global variable is by "storing" the variable (or input) in a function (and the function also is a variable), and storing the function into another function by "passing it"; in the end, all the functions in the chain become a single function that folds multiple smaller functions.

Example:

```
(+2) >>= \a-> (+3) >>= \b -> return(a+b)
```

Based on the tutorial, `>>=` works like this `f >>= g = \w -> g (f w) w`
so what I understand is we are getting a function that takes two inputs, a `w` (variable) and a function (that also uses that variable)
and output `((+3) w)`.  Here, `w` was the input.

So this line:

```
(+2) >>= \a-> (+3) >>= \b -> return(a+b)
```

is equivalent to

```
 \w -> (\(2+w) -> (+3)  w) >>=\b -> return (a+b)
                                 a
```

(and this `2+w` function been "stored" in `(\a->(+3))`'s first input `\a`).

Similarly:

```
\w2 -> (\b ->return (...))  ( \w -> (\(2+w) -> (+3)  w) ) w2
```

and `\b` is stored in the `\w -> (\(2+w) -> (+3)  w)`:

```
\w2 -> (  \(( \w -> (\(2+w) -> (+3)  w) ) -> return(...)) w2
```

Then, the `return (a+b)` is not actually just simply doing `return x = \_ -> x`, but is also able to take functions (`a` and `b`) out of that big function `\w2 -> (  \b(a inside) -> return(...)) w2` to get another big function:

```
( (\w -> 2+w) +(\w -> (\(2+w) -> (+3)  w) )
```

Do I understand it correctly?  Or am I entirely wrong. I didn't find any tutorial that talked about `return` (taking input from function).   Monads are still very confusing to me.

Comment: Do you realize that you're describing just how the Monad instance for functions works, not how monads in general work, and that other monads all work differently?

Comment: Don't learn monads by one example. There is a joke saying "once you learn what a monad is, just lose the ability to explain it". Such joke hides a truth: monads _are_ an abstract concept, and looking to one example of monad instance will reveal a small part of such abstraction. Imagine you want to learn what a class is, just by looking an instance of it... kind of the same thing for monads. Read all you can about `Maybe`, `Reader` and `State` monads and try to figure out the common pattern they share, then move on to others. I'd suggest monday morning haskell blog for begginers material.

Comment: Monads: Kleisli Arrows [*compose*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) associatively, with [`return`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) being an identity for that composition.

Comment: your post is very badly formatted, to the point that it becomes nearly incomprehensible. generally, *ask **one** question at a time*. it is OK and in fact good and proper to post lots of small, focused questions. you can always include links to your previous relevant posts. you could start by editing this one. :) if you do, please @ ping me.

Comment: If you want to understand the concept of a monad, study how the implementations for any particular monad obey the monad *laws*. This will help you see the similarities between different monads that simple term-level effects hide.

Comment: I'd say the reader type encodes rather the idea of global constants than global variables. `local` does mimic variables though. It allows a name binding to have different values but only in different function scopes.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you are describing one specific monad, the "reader" monad.  At the level of detail you're trying to understand it, this reader monad will behave differently from other monads.

That said, I think your understanding of the detailed operation of the reader monad is *partially* correct.  However, you've missed a couple of things:  you've messed up the precise order of operations in your example expression that's dictated by how lambda expressions are parsed, and you've sort of glossed over the "merge" step that combines the `\w -> ...` lambdas that are introduced by each `>>=` operator so they all refer to the same global variable.

To make it a little clearer, let me spell it out in detail, using simple transformations of expressions that match the way GHC would actually evaluate your code...

Let's take your example:

```
(+2) >>= \a -> (+3) >>= \b -> return (a+b)
```

and start by inserting some parenthesis.  Even though the operator `>>=` is left associative, lambda expressions like `\a -> ...` suck up as much valid expression as they can, so the correct placement of parentheses in this expression is:

```
(+2) >>= ( \a -> ( (+3) >>= ( \b -> return (a+b) ) ) )         -- (1)
```

Now, as you note, the definition of `>>=` is:

```
f >>= g = \w -> g (f w) w
```

Also, the definition of `return` is:

```
return x = \w -> x
```

so let's work on the expression for the right-most occurrence of `>>=` in (1):

```
(+3) >>= ( \b -> return (a+b) )
=   -- apply definition of `>>=` with f = (+3); g = \b -> return (a+b)
\w -> (\b -> return (a+b)) ((+3) w) w
=   -- apply lambda expression (\b -> ...) to first argument ((+3) w)
\w -> (return (a + (+3) w)) w
=   -- apply definition of `return` (with renamed variable w')
\w -> (\w' -> a + (+3) w) w
=   -- apply lambda expression (\w' -> ...) to first argument w
\w -> a + (+3) w
```

So, we have:

```
(+3) >>= ( \b -> return (a+b) )    ===    \w -> a + (+3) w     -- (2)
```

and, in a *sense*, the operator `>>=` works by passing the function `(+3)` as the argument `b`.  However, it doesn't literally do this, because the argument `b` has numeric type, not function type.  Instead, it "pulls out" a lambda for the "global variable" `\w -> ...` and then passes `(+3) w` as `b`, which works fine, since `(+3) w` has a numeric type.

Now, let's look at the original example (1) with the substitution (2):

```
-- from (1) and the subsitution (2):
(+2) >>= ( \a -> ( \w -> a + (+3) w ) )
=   -- apply defn of >>= with f = (+2); g = \a -> (\w -> a + (+3) w)
\w' -> (\a -> (\w -> a + (+3) w)) ((+2) w') w'
=   -- apply lambda (\a -> ...) to ((+2) w')
\w' -> (\w -> (+2) w' + (+3) w) w'
=   -- apply lambda (\w -> ...) to w'
\w' -> (+2) w' + (+3) w'
```

and, again, in a *sense*, the operator `>>=` works by passing the function `(+2)` as argument `a`.  Since it can't do it literatlly, it does it by pullling a lambda for the "global variable" `\w' -> ...` out and passing `(+2) w'` as `a`, and then it sort of "merges" the `\w -> ...` lambda pulled out by the rightmost `>>=` operator with the `\w' -> ...` it's added, so they point to the same global variable.

Obviously, if we added additional similar binds on the left:

```
(+8) >>= \e -> (+1) >>= \o -> (+2) >>= \a -> (+3) >>= \b -> return (e+o+a+b)
```

we'd get the same pattern of adding a new lambda `\w' -> ...` for the global variable and then "merging" it with the existing lambda `\w -> ...`:

```
\w -> (+8) w + (+1) w + (+2) w + (+3) w
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s go through your example step by step in two ways. First, let’s see what the `do` notation equivalent is:

```
do
  a <- (+ 2)
  b <- (+ 3)
  return (a + b)
```

This is essentially an abstraction over the following repetitive pattern, where many different functions are all applied to the same shared “environment” value and then there’s some final result returned:

```
\ env -> let
  a = (+ 2) env
  b = (+ 3) env
  in (a + b)
```

In fact, for consistency with the other actions, the `return` also receives the environment, and just ignores it:

```
\ env -> let
  a = (+ 2) env
  b = (+ 3) env
  in const (a + b) env  -- const x y = x
```

We can make this fit the `Monad` pattern by having `>>=` carry this environment along and pass it to each function (`(+ 2)`, `(+ 3)`, `const (a + b)`).

`>>=` takes two functions `function` and `continue`, where `function` is one of `(+ 2)` or `(+ 3)` above; `>>=` applies `function` to the environment, and then passes two things along to `continue`: the result of `function`, and the environment again, so that subsequent steps in `continue` can also read the environment.

```
-- Type:
(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m        a -> (a -> m        b) -> m        b
-- or:
(>>=) ::              (->) env a -> (a -> (->) env b) -> (->) env b
-- or:
(>>=) ::              (env -> a) -> (a -> env ->   b) -> env ->   b

-- Implementation:
instance Monad ((->) env) where

  function >>= continue = \ env -> continue (function env) env
  -- or:
  (>>=) = \ function continue env -> continue (function env) env
```

In fact, with the `{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}` extension, you can write exactly the last type above as the signature for `>>=` in the `Monad` instance, and I recommend using that extension to help you implement typeclasses as you’re learning.

`return` takes a value `x`, and produces a function that fits in place of `continue` above, which, as I mentioned before, just ignores the environment and returns `x`.

```
return x = \ _env -> x
-- =
return = \ x _env -> x
-- =
return = const
```

Now secondly, if we go back to the desugared `do` notation, and add parentheses to clarify the scope of the lambdas:

```
(+ 2) >>= (\ a -> (+ 3) >>= (\ b -> return (a + b)))
```

Then we can inline those definitions of `>>=` and `return` to see how they work in this context. I’ve numbered the variables in each substitution to make the scopes a little more explicit.

```
(\ function1 continue1 env1 -> continue1 (function1 env1) env1)
  (+ 2)
  (\ a ->
    (\ function2 continue2 env2 -> continue2 (function2 env2) env2)
      (+ 3)
      (\ b ->
        (\ x env3 -> x)
          (a + b)))
```

Then we can substitute all the variables throughout, by applying the functions to their arguments (*beta-reduction*):

```
let
  function1 = (+ 2)
  continue1 = \ a ->
    let
      function2 = (+ 3)
      continue2 = \ b ->
        let
          x = (a + b)
        in \ _env3 -> x

    in \ env2 -> continue2 (function2 env2) env2

in \ env1 -> continue1 (function1 env1) env1)

-- =

\ env1 ->
  (\ a env2 ->
    (\ b _env3 -> a + b)
      (env2 + 3)
      env2)
    (env1 + 2)
    env1

-- =

\ env1 -> let
  a = (env1 + 2)
  env2 = env1
  in let
    b = (env2 + 3)
    _env3 = env2
    in (a + b)
```

Then we can omit all the redundant `env` variables, since they’re all equal to each other, and just used to pass the value along to all the functions:

```
\ env -> let
  a = (env + 2)
  b = (env + 3)
  in (a + b)
```

And this is exactly the code we were trying to abstract away!

This is only one `Monad` instance, though; all other instances work differently based on the specific type involved. What all the basic instances have in common is that they abstract over some common repetitive pattern in pure code, e.g.:

```
-- State:

\ state1 -> let
  (a, state2) = function1 state1
  (b, state3) = function2 state2
  (c, state4) = function3 state3
  …
  in (x, stateX)

-- Writer:

\ log1 -> let
  (a, log2) = function1
  (b, log3) = function2
  (c, log4) = function3
  …
  in (x, log1 <> log2 <> log3 <> log4)

-- Maybe:

case function1 of
  Just a -> case function2 of
    Just b -> case function3 of
      Just c -> …
          Just x -> Just x
          Nothing -> Nothing
      Nothing -> Nothing
    Nothing -> Nothing
  Nothing -> Nothing

-- Either:

case function1 of
  Right a -> case function2 of
    Right b -> case function3 of
      Right c -> …
          Right x -> Right x
          Left errorX -> Left errorX
      Left error3 -> Left error3
    Left error2 -> Left error2
  Left error1 -> Left error1

-- List:

concatMap
  (\ a -> concatMap
    (\ b -> concatMap
      (\ c -> concatMap
          …
         [x])
      function3)
    function2)
  function1
```

Likewise, the basic monad *transformers* abstract over such patterns in monadic code.

```
-- MaybeT:

do
  ma <- function1
  case ma of
    Just a -> do
      mb <- function2
      case mb of
        Just b -> do
          mc <- function3
          case mc of
            Just c -> …
                Just x -> pure (Just x)
                Nothing -> pure Nothing
            Nothing -> pure Nothing
        Nothing -> pure Nothing
      Nothing -> pure Nothing
    Nothing -> pure Nothing
```

The `Monad`/`Applicative`/`Functor` hierarchy provide a common way for data structures and control structures to abstract over some kind of sequential pattern like this so they can *all* be used with `do` notation and library functions like `replicateM` that work for *any* `Monad`.

It helps to look at *lots* of different examples, not just one instance, to get a feel for what they have in common and how they differ.

Comment: Great explanation. Why do we need `env` as an argument in the first place? Functions are naturally global, because they are pure. Constant values are also pure. Functions are pure values. What is the risk of being dependent on global constants? Anyway, I know this is off-topic and not appropriate for a comment. I should file a question..

Comment: @bob it's just an abstraction, with which we have less typing to do (so less chance to make an error, too). `do { x <- (+1) ; y <- (*2) ; return (x+y) }` is shorter than the corresponding `let`. Similarly with the state passing, or non-value handling. we don't *need* monad for that, we could type in all that verbose code explicitly. Lisp has macros, Haskell has the more principled approach with monads. --- there's also MonadComprehensions extension, e.g. `[ x+y | x <- (+1), y <- (*2) ]`, inching ever closer to the pseudocode `for` comprehensions, `{ x+y FOR x FROM (+1) AND y FROM (*2) }` etc.

Comment: @bob as always, Haskell's naming is off. `do` should've been named `for`, and `return` - `yield`.

Comment: @bob: It becomes much more convenient if you want to make *local modifications* to the environment with [`local`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:local). `Reader`/`ReaderT` allows the environment to be *dynamic*, while a global variable is necessarily static. If you already have `IO` available, it’s more efficient to use `data MutEnv = MutEnv { envMutableStuff :: IORef Stuff }` and `ReaderT MutEnv IO` than the pure `data Env = Env { envStuff :: Stuff }` with `StateT Env IO`, and a global `IORef` would require unsafe code.